# Chrome dev tool - Fetch javascript files without reload webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I've been trying to find in Chrome dev tool a way to reload javascript files without the need of reload the whole webpage. Search on google and SO but no luck so far.

The use case is I have a cart form that has 5 steps to finish purchase. After update javascript file, I don't want to reload the page and enter all information from step 1 thru step 5 to see if it works. It's very time consuming.

Anyone experienced with this tool please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by fetching your script in the **Console**, creating a script element, setting the content of the script to the text that you fetched, and then inserting the new script element into your document.

```
fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js').then(response => {
    return response.text();
}).then(text => {
    let s = document.createElement('script');
    s.textContent = text;
    document.head.appendChild(s);
});
```

[image: lodash example]

For example, suppose that I want to run the Lodash library from my page, which you usually do by calling `_` (like how you call `$` to use jQuery). In the GIF when I click the button it just executes `console.log(_)`. The first time I click, the Console says that `_` is undefined. After I run the code, `_` successfully points to the Lodash library.

If your page has a lot of iframes, make sure that you insert the library into the correct document. That's why I select `fiddle.jshell.net` from the [Context Selector dropdown menu](/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#execution-context).